# Multiple Table Inheritance vs Polymorphic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multiple-inheritance, polymorphic-associations

I’m creating an app that allows a user to create a course and include different types of resources (document, video, quiz) in the course. I’m having a hard time figuring out the best way to set up association between a course and its resources.

Right now, I have:

```
    class Course < AR::Base
      has_many :documents
      has_many :videos
      has_many :quizzes
    end

    class Document <AR::Base
      belongs_to :course
    end

    class Video <AR::Base
      belongs_to :course
    end

    class Quiz <AR::Base
      belongs_to :course
    end
```

Documents, Videos, and Quizzes all have some common attributes (e.g., name, description) but also many attributes that differ. I considered using STI and having them inherit from a single class called “Lessons.” I decided against this approach because I need multiple controllers for each class.

Ultimately, I want to be able to perform operations on all the resources that belong to a course so for example list all the documents, videos, and quizzes together and display them as a sortable list.

Any suggestions on how best to set up this model. It seems as if I could do it two ways:

- Reverse polymorphic has_one association (see [example](https://gist.github.com/1242485))
- Multiple Table inheritance (see [example](http://mediumexposure.com/multiple-table-inheritance-active-record/))

I’m a rails noob so I’m having a hard time evaluating which approach is best for this situation. Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> Ultimately, I want to be able to perform operations on all the resources that belong to a course so for example list all the documents, videos, and quizzes together and display them as a sortable list.

Either approach is doable, but when I read this requirement, it seems you'd be best off with STI. STI is a natively supported feature in rails and allows you to query and manipulate different types of resources within the same collection.